# Issues with melt() in R not matching names?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the following df from wide to long

Input:

```
structure(list(activity_level = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Sedentary", 
"Lightly Active", "Moderately Active", "Very Active"), class = "factor"), 
    poor_sleepers = c(0.254032258064516, 0.258695652173913, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.253119429590018), normal_sleepers = c(0.332661290322581, 
    0.360869565217391, 0.318181818181818, 0.42602495543672), 
    excess_sleepers = c(0.413306451612903, 0.380434782608696, 
    0.348484848484849, 0.320855614973262)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Using the following line and the melt function:

```
daily_sleep_byActivity_long <- melt(daily_sleep_byActivity, id.vars = "activity_level")
```

So that I get a result like this:

```
    structure(list(user_type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Sedentary", "Lightly Active", 
"Fairly Active", "Very Active"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("bad_sleepers", 
"normal_sleepers", "over_sleepers"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.32076169347384, 
0.0601633003867641, 0.133333333333333, 0.175548589341693, 0.594379737474579, 
0.778685002148689, 0.866666666666667, 0.824451410658307, 0.0848585690515807, 
0.161151697464547, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

As far as I can tell, my syntax is clear and the input has all the correct formats, but my out put tells me "names do not match previous names". Does anyone know if I have missed something? My research online hasn't addressed this question.

Comment: There are `melt` functions in many packages (`reshape`, `reshape2`, `data.table`, ...). Which one are you using?

Comment: When I run your code and specify `reshape2::melt` I get a reasonable looking result. The sample output in your question doesn't seem to actually match the input...

Comment: @GregorThomas, thank you for clarifying that, I was using reshape instead of reshape2. This fixed my issue right away. Thank you!